# Some <Super>+<Letter> shortcuts don't work with Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, 22.04, shortcut-keys

I've made a fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04 and I have some problems. I have defined some custom keyboard shortcuts using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd> keys, but some of them don't work. I was previously using Xubuntu 16.04 and I didn't have this problem.

#### The problem

For a basic example, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut doesn't launch my web browser: if the focused window is a terminal it prints `w` (as if I only pressed <kbd>w</kbd>).

- Important detail : I have an external AZERTY keyboard (so the <kbd>w</kbd> key is located just above the left <kbd>Super</kbd> key).
- Interesting detail 1: if I change the command associated with this shortcut, it works well... until the next reboot.
- Interesting detail 2: some shortcuts with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd> work, depending on the <kbd>Letter</kbd> key I use.

#### Letters affected by this problem

For a wider view, I tested the shortcuts with all the letters of my keyboard and looked at my terminal window to see if letters are printed or not. Here are the printed letters (so shortcuts with <kbd>Super</kbd> + these keys will not work):

```
-----yuio-
q---ghjk-m
wxcvbn
```

I represented them on the rows of my keyboard (3 rows of letters), and `-` means that the corresponding letter doesn't print anything (so the shortcuts with those letters work).

If it helps to understand, here are the letters that work (no letter printed in my terminal window):

```
azert----p
-sdf----l-
------
```

#### More details

I tried to see what happens and I discovered the `xev` command.
Here is the result of `xev -event keyboard` and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> pressed (shortcut doesn't work):

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 7273892, (165,-11), root:(1036,524),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 7274156, (165,-11), root:(1036,524),
    state 0x50, keycode 52 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 7274244, (165,-11), root:(1036,524),
    state 0x50, keycode 52 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 7274396, (165,-11), root:(1036,524),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is the result of `xev -event keyboard` and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> pressed **after redefining the executed command** (shortcut works):

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 8245188, (166,-9), root:(1037,526),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967241 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 8245796, (166,-9), root:(1037,526),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

#### My analysis

I guess the system doesn't handle some <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd> key combinations. After redefining a shortcut it works. So something is different, but I don't know what (and it isn't permanent as the problem comes back after reboot).
I clearly see that the `keymapNotify` event is not fired, but I have no idea why (and I don't know how it works).

I hope someone can help me. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more details.